# Background-Image in CSS w/ div produced by

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set a background image to a modal that is created in JS. The photo I have is saved in: `/../assets/img/blah.png` and I cannot get it to display in the div.

The JS code does create a class and ID attr for the div that is displayed in the HTML page. I tried grabbing the ID/class in CSS and used `<i>background-image: url("/../assets/img/gamehub-favicon.png");</i>` but that doesn't work.

Can someone please assist?

Comment: cannot understand your question.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<i>background-image: url("/../assets/img/gamehub-favicon.png");</i>
```

seems to be wrong

If the html is like this

```
<i class='iconBck'></i>
```

then in css do like this

```
.iconBck{
   background-image: url("/../assets/img/gamehub-favicon.png");
}
```